# Bringing back cmd while using shift+RMB

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, powershell, cmd.exe, context-menu

For question of comodity i want to bring back the command prompt in the menu while using the combination `Shift+RMB`, instead of having to use Windows Powershell, that, let's say this, it is pretty much unuseful for what I need to do.

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: [How do I start PowerShell from Windows Explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183901/how-do-i-start-powershell-from-windows-explorer), yes the title says PowerShell. But go read and try to adapt.

Comment: Not quite the solution I wanted to, will try once I'm home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once did this myself (but the other way round), and in the meanwhile, I forgot where one could find the setting. [But it was nothing a quick googlelin' couldn't help me with](https://www.google.at/webhp#q=win10+switch+back+to+cmd):

- Open the new Control Panel (e.g. via right-clicking on the task-bar and clicking on "Task Bar settings")
- Go to "Personalization" - "Taskbar"
- Turn off "Replace Command Prompt with PowerShell".